# Reading or loading JSON file from another module

Tags: java, json, maven, resources

I want to read/load a `JSON` file from another module's `/resources` directory to the current module and map the `JSON` using `jackson`.

Current module name is "transform" and the resource file that I need is in another module named "schema". I have added "schema" as a `maven` `dependency` in the `pom.xml` file of the "transform" module.

I need to read/load a file named "example.json" in the "schema" module.

But I keep getting the following error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input`.

What I have so far:

```
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.readValue(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/schema/resources/example.json"),
                                                new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

Let's just say the full path to example.json is "/schema/resources/example.json".

Comment: Have a try with the following maven plugin [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292283/use-a-dependencys-resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292283/use-a-dependencys-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.readValue(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/schema/resources/example.json"),
                                            new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something very similar and it worked. Here is what I did: `objectMapper.readValue(MyClassInDifferentModule.class.getResourceAsStream("/schema/resources/example.json"), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){});`