# How Can One Include Resources From Another Module In A Spring Boot Maven Multi Module Project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a spring boot mavel multi-module project.

If the spring boot module depends on module `A` and in the `src/main/resources` folder of module `A` there is a properties file or some other resource that I want bundled in the final spring boot app, how can I achieve this.

Currently, if I run `jar -tf` on the module A JAR it includes the file:

```
jar -tf module-a/target/module-a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep changelog

db/changelog/
db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

However:

```
jar -tf boot-module/target/boot-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep changelog | wc -l
       0
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: did you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448530/3892213

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I believe you can use the `unpack` goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin` in your Spring Boot module:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <includes>**/*.yaml</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That will copy the resources from `module-a` to `boot-module`. I've posted a complete example on [GitHub](https://github.com/jjlharrison/copy-resources-example).