# Spring Boot Maven Plugin Include Resources

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

## Example

Is it possible to somehow configure the spring boot maven plugin to include resources from a dependency.

E.g. if in my spring boot project I have:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>co.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

and in that JAR file there is a properties file such as `example.properties`

```
jar -tf example.jar | grep example.properties | wc -l
```

results in 1.

However, when I build the spring boot JAR, this properties file is not added to the `src/main/resources`. The JAR containing it is included in `BOOT-INF/lib/example.jar`

However, in my case. I'd like to extract the content of `src/main/resources` out into the boot `BOOT-INF/classes/` directory of the spring boot JAR so that things like auto configuration can pick it up.

## Real World

In the real world, i'm trying to do this with:

- thymeleaf templates (e.g. my dependency JAR provides the HTML template files but in the deployed boot jar these templates are not resolved)
- liquibase changelog files (my dependency includes changelog files but these aren't executed - I presume liquibase autoconfig doesn't find the changelog file because it's not in the `src/main/resources` of the boot JAR).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the solution for this problem would be very similar to the [solution for another question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786625/how-can-one-include-resources-from-another-module-in-a-spring-boot-maven-multi-m/48938588#48938588).

You can use the `unpack` goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin` in your Spring Boot module:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <includes>**/*.yaml</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/BOOT-INF/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That will copy the resources from `module-a` to `BOOT-INF` directory of your `boot-module`. I've posted a more complete example on [GitHub](https://github.com/jjlharrison/copy-resources-example).