# How to load resources only from a dependency maven module

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 maven modules A and B. Both have java classes in src/main/java and resources in src/main/resources. A depends on B so B is referenced in the A's pom.

It works but actually A depends on B only because A needs some resources from B.

Is there any solution for pulling only resources of B without pulling all the B project ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a dependency's resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292283/use-a-dependencys-resources)

Comment: You could extract the resources A relies on in another project C which would only contain those resources and which would be a dependency of both A and B

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the maven-dependency-plugin for that. You can copy the whole or parts of artifacts with that without the need of **depending** on that artifact.

Please see this example to get a clue:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html